# Show/hide icon when hovering over table row using jquery tables plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working with jQuery table datatable plugin and want to show/hide an icon when hovering over table row.

I have tried to do this, in CSS with:

```
#pencil{
   display:none
} 
.pencil-wrapper:hover + #pencil{
   display:inline-table
}
```

However since I'm using jQuery table plugin, maybe there is a way to do it inside the `$('#').DataTable();` object.

```
<td>
   <span id="pencil-wrapper">
       <i id="pecil" class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
   </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Some problems with your current code: in CSS you use `#pencil` in html it's `id="pecil"`, a typo with "n". in CSS you use `.pencil-wrapper` (a class), but in html you have `pencil-wrapper` as an id. Also, a span without content will have no height or width, so it won't be hoverable

Comment: and in CSS, a `+` selector means an element immediately after (but not inside), so it won't work, you'll need a `>` selector, that selects the first child